# add background image in iphone using IB

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to add a background image for some labels in my custom view. How do I add the same? If I use UIImageView, it comes as foreground image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the specific imageview in IB, then select Layout from the top menu, and click send to back. Or do the same with the label but select bring to front :)

Comment: Perfect answer...Works great.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to control visibility in IB, just view the .xib file in list mode.   Items listed farther down in the list appear on top of elements above them in the list.   So to place a background image under a label, drag the UIImageView into the view, and drag it to be above the labels in the view list.   Like  this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add that labels as subviews for that image view.

Comment: I am using IB. Can I still do it ?

Comment: Yes, just switch to tree mode in the XIB property window.

Comment: http://pixel.recoil.org/rococoa/Nib.png - here on image where View mode chose the middle one and drag labels to your image view